# No-longer-dupe requires reopening?

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

The original question is gone so this question [Exception inside catch block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901149/exception-inside-catch-block) is not longer a dupe and should be re-opened.

(I've flagged this situation before and find it odd the system doesn't automatically know to flag this situation. )

Comment: I'm sure it's still a dupe of several questions at least. Such as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555567/when-is-finally-run-if-you-throw-an-exception-from-the-catch-block

Answer (score 4):

Formalizing bemace's comment, there are many, many duplicates of this question, including but not limited to:

- [In .NET, what if something fails in the catch block, will finally always get called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582095/in-net-what-if-something-fails-in-the-catch-block-will-finally-always-get-call)
- [Does a finally block always run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464098/does-a-finally-block-always-run)
- [Conditions when finally does not execute in a .net try..finally block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111597/conditions-when-finally-does-not-execute-in-a-net-try-finally-block)
- [Will code in a Finally statement fire if I return a value in a Try block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345091/will-code-in-a-finally-statement-fire-if-i-return-a-value-in-a-try-block)

No need to reopen this question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the chain of events.

1. **5/7/2009** Question ID: **833946** asks "In C# will the Finally block be executed in a try, catch, finally if an unhandled exception is thrown?"
2. **5/7/2009** Question ID: **833946** is closed as duplicate (with the four links inside the question)
3. **5/23/2009** Question ID: **901149** asks "Exception inside catch block"
4. **5/23/2009** Question ID: **901149** is closed as duplicate with reference to 833946
5. **5/11/2010** Question ID: **833946** is deleted, making an "orphan" out of 901149

I think it is valid to say we probably shouldn't be marking a question closed as duplicate to a question that is already a duplicate but rather one of the four that are still open.

It would also be valid if when a question gets deleted because it is a dupe it also deletes questions, which are marked as duplicate, referring to it.

In any case, the only reason to reopen 901149 would be to mark it as duplicate of one of the other four but it is probably going to be deleted anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately, duplicates aren't supposed to be deleted, but some mods hate them so much, they're willing to break the rules.

Comment: @lance I wasn't aware of that

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been solved in a different way: [The original duplicate question has been undeleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833946/in-c-will-the-finally-block-be-executed-in-a-try-catch-finally-if-an-unhandled).

Probably the better solution, as that question has a lot better answers already. There seems little point in re-opening the proposed question and allowing them to be duplicated again.

Comment: It's curious the question with the alleged better answers was deleted. Thanks for doing this.